# Sprite frame as div background, auto scales wrongly on div rotation

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, scale, css-transforms

As the title suggests, I'm rendering a frame of a sprite on a div background.

That all works fine, and resizes correctly just until a rotation is applied on the div.
When the image is first loads in the rotated div, the scale is correct, but if we resize the document, the frame scale becomes incorrect.

Please see this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/irith/b4s1vekn/). To replicate the issue just resize the "result" section.

Code:

HTML

```
<div class="img"></div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.img {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/orange-mushroom-game-sprites_22191-71.jpg);
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
}
```

JS

```
const $img = document.querySelector('.img');

const firstFrameWidth = 185;
const firstFrameHeight = 155;
const firstFrameX = 0;
const firstFrameY = -10;

const spriteWidth = 626;
const spriteHeight = 348;

function resize() {
  const bounds = $img.getBoundingClientRect();
  const scaleX = bounds.width / firstFrameWidth;
  const scaleY = bounds.height / firstFrameHeight;
  const bgWidth = spriteWidth * scaleX;
  const bgHeight = spriteHeight * scaleY;
  const bgX = firstFrameX * scaleX;
  const bgY = firstFrameY * scaleY;

  $img.style.backgroundSize = `${bgWidth}px ${bgHeight}px`;
  $img.style.backgroundPosition = `${firstFrameX}px ${firstFrameY}px`;
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
resize();

$img.style.transform = 'rotate(45deg)';
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I actually figure out much later that getBoundingClientRect returns different values from window.getComputedStyles...apparently like you said, getBoundingClientRect returns the height and width post rotation, but I needed the original height and width to scale the sprite so the trick was to use window.getComputedStyle.